# '' equals false in Javascript? What would be the safest way to distinguish between '' and boolean false?

Tags: javascript

We use an external API whcih returns '' or boolean false while Javascript seems to find the both equal.
for example:

```
var x = '';
if (!x) {
  alert(x); // the alert box is shown - empty

}
if (x=='') {
  alert(x); // the alert box is shown here too  - empty

}
var z = false;
if (!z) {
  alert(z); // the alert box is shown - displays 'false'

}
if (z=='') {
  alert(z); // the alert box is shown here too - displays 'false'

}
```

How can we distinguish between the two?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use the triple equal

```
if (x===false) //false as expected
if (z==='') //false as expected
```

A double equal will do type casting, while triple equal will not. So:

```
0 == "0" //true
0 === "0" //false, since the first is an int, and the second is a string
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var typeX = typeof(x);
var typeZ = typeof(z);

if (typeX == 'string' && x == '')
else if (typeX == 'boolean' && !typeX)
```

I like Peirix's answer too, but here is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by peirix: tripple equal signs check both the value and the **type**

```
1 == '1' // true
1 === '1' // false
```

Comment: As you mentioned, it's been mentioned before. Why mention it again?

Comment: because at the time I posted this he failed to mention that it checks for value AND type...

Answer (score 0):

For avoid this questions use jslint validator. It helps for find unsafe operations.